# Java - Calling paint method from different class?

Tags: java, swing, class, paint, repaint

I have a class which extends JFrame and creates a window and it needs to call the paint() method which is in a different class.  I understand that if they were in the same class, the setVisible(true) would call the paint method, but since they are in different classes, it does not. I have created objects of the Die class (the one painting), but I don't know how to use them to call the paint method.

This is the class which creates the window:

```
public class Game extends Frame 
{

    public void window()
    {   
        setTitle("Roll");   //  Title of the window
        setLocation(100, 100);          //  Location of the window
        setSize(900, 600);              //  Size of the window
        setBackground(Color.lightGray); //  Color of the window
        setVisible(true);               //  Make it appear and call paint

    }
```

And for the paint method in the other class called Die, I used:

```
public void paint(Graphics pane)
```

Comment: General answer: you either need a reference to `Die` inside your `Game` class by calling the constructor `Die die = new Die()` and then calling the paint method `die.paint()` or inside `Die` class you make the `paint()` method `static` and then call it as such `Die.paint()`.

Comment: @nem already tried that first one and the second one doesn't work because I have to return value?

Comment: `paint()` method has `void` return type so it doesn't need to return anything in both cases

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you could pass the `Die` instance into the `Game` constructor with something like

```
public class Game extends Frame {
  private Die die;
  public Game(Die die) {
    this.die = die;
  }
  public void window() {    
    setTitle("Roll");   //  Title of the window
    setLocation(100, 100);          //  Location of the window
    setSize(900, 600);              //  Size of the window
    setBackground(Color.lightGray); //  Color of the window
    setVisible(true);               //  Make it appear and call paint
    die.setVisible(true);           //  The same
  }
}
```

Then, wherever you call `new Game()` you add the `Die` instance argument. This is a fairly common way to implement a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) in Java (and other OOP languages).

Comment: Not sure I understand this. The Game class has-a Die. The idea is that I am calling the Die class, which creates a die using several methods, in the Game class multiple times to create a die. Should also note there is a setup method before the paint method in the Die class.

Comment: @John Yes. This establishes a has-a relationship. If you already had one then your question makes no sense. If you need to call it multiple times that's fine, you already have one.

Comment: When I try to create a new Game(), it tells me the constructor Game() is undefined. And when I have new Game(Die) it tells me Die cannot be resolved to a variable. But I still don't see how I would need a new Game() in the Die class?

Comment: Pass the `Die` instance. `new Game(new Die())` or the `Die` instance you have initialized... `new Game(someInitializedDie)`

Comment: Oh, I see. But now what do I call in the main method? It tells me the constructor game is undefined when I use                                                 Game myGameTable = new Game(); 
myGameTable.window();

Comment: If you want to draw the `Die` in `Game` then they need to exist before you create the `Game` or you need to create them in `Game`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The Game class creates a game for the user to play. They input information which is then used in the Die class to created two die. All I need to do is call the Die class, specifically the paint method(), from within my Game class so it can paint two die.

Comment: Above, remove the constructor change and change the `die.setVisible(true)` to `yourFirstDie.setVisible(true);` and `yourSecondDie.setVisible(true);`. Next time include enough code to make your question clear.

Comment: It's still not working. Let me ask a different way. I can always just call the setup() method from the Game class, is there a way to then call the paint() method from the setup method? I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Don't call `paint()`. You need to let your Components draw themselves. Also, your `window()` has two dice? Just set them visible.

Comment: 1+ your answer but 1- to the OP for re-asking this question, and using a different identity -- which is why I sort of remembered seeing this question, but I couldn't find it!

Comment: I have flagged the moderators to this.