# Calling paint method from class which doesn't extend JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paint

I have a class `Game` which extends JFrame and create the window I want to paint on. Then I have this class `Die`which paints what I want. From `Game` I can just call the `setup()` method in the `Die` class, but how do I then call the paint() method?

```
public class Die 
{   
    private int xA, yA;                 
    private int dieNumber;  

    public void setup(int someX, int someY, int someValue) {
        dieNumber = someValue;
        xA = someX;
        yA = someY;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics pane) {  

        drawBlank(pane);                

        if (dieNumber == 1){        
            drawOne(pane);  }   
        else if (dieNumber == 2){
            drawTwo(pane);  }
        else if (dieNumber == 3){

          ......
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? Regardless, you should try to create and post a [minimal example program or MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program that we can run and compile and that will show us your problem. There's a lot of pertinent code that you still need to show us -- but without showing us too much code, which is where the MCVE will help. You likely are doing graphics in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method and if so, should call your Die object's paint method inside of the paintComponent method. But heck, I'm just making wild guesses. Please show more.

Comment: [Again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472497/java-calling-paint-method-from-different-class)? I [say](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474594/java-calling-paint-method-from-window-method-in-another-class).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am doing graphics in a JFrame's paint(...). I mentioned it in the description. My apologies if it was not clear enough. But why can't I just call paint() from setup()?

Comment: @John: no, never do graphics in a JFrame's paint method. Please read the Swing Graphics tutorials before going forward with this. With regards to why you can't call paint from setup -- Swing graphics are passive and cannot be called on command. You should instead do as I recommend, and suggest to the paint managher that painting be done by calling repaint() on the JPanel. But again, this is explained in the tutorial that you have not yet read. So first and foremost, fix this -- read the tutorial.

Comment: *"Calling paint method from class which doesn't extend JFrame"*  As an aside, I have never seen a good reason to extend `JFrame`.  Why is this code doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You would likely do your graphics in the `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override of a JPanel, and inside that method, call `die.paint(g)` on any Die objects that you need to draw.

e.g.,

```
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private Die die1 = new Die();
    private Die die2 = new Die();
    //.....

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        die1.paint(g);
        die2.paint(g);

    }

}
```

For more specific and detailed help, please try to create and post a [minimal example program or MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program that we can run and compile and that will show us your problem. There's a lot of pertinent code that you still need to show us -- but without showing us too much code, which is where the MCVE will help.

Also never do graphics in a JFrame's or Frame's paint method, and you shouldn't use Frame or AWT components anyway. Please read the Swing Graphics tutorials before going forward with this. With regards to why you can't call paint from setup -- Swing graphics are passive and cannot be called on command. You should instead do as I recommend, and suggest to the paint managher that painting be done by calling repaint() on the JPanel. But again, this is explained in the tutorial that you have not yet read. So first and foremost, fix this -- read the tutorial.

Swing tutorials can be found from this link: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Answer (score 2):

It is a far more better approach if your die extends JPanel and make the custom drawing overriding the paintComponent:

```
public class Die extends JPanel
{   
    private int xA, yA;                 
    private int dieNumber;  

    public void setup(int someX, int someY, int someValue) {
        dieNumber = someValue;
        xA = someX;
        yA = someY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics pane) {  
        super.painComponent(pane);             

        if (dieNumber == 1){        
            drawOne(pane);  }   
        else if (dieNumber == 2){
            drawTwo(pane);  }
        else if (dieNumber == 3){

        ......
    }
```